# Tomcat: Accessing java web application without port number

Tags: tomcat

i am running my java web application using tomcat server and i am accessing it with the url  "//localhost:8080/Authority/" .
But i want to access it using "//localhost/Authority/" .
Pls help me out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the http port is not specifier, it is assumed to be port 80. So your web container must listen on port 80.
But on a Unix-like OS, only root can listen to a port number lower that 1024.

Anyway; to change the port number, you need to edit tomcat's server.xml file and change the port number of the http <Connector>

Comment: I hv changed it to port:80. still its asking me to enter 8080 while accessing

Comment: Did you restart tomcat?